# Basic MySQL question: how to get rows from one table that are not in another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of usernames (with a column called "username") + other info in my "users" table.

I also have another list of usernames (with a column called "username") in my smaller "recentusers" table.

**How can I create a mysql query to get all the usernames that are in the "users" table but not in the "recentusers" table?**

I know it is probably very simple, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select username from users where username not in (select username from recentusers)
```

Then after the first username add in the other information you want to select as well.

As pointed out by OMG Ponies, this query will run as fast as using [Left Join or Is null.](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: FYI: This will run as fast as a query using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Excellent information. I did not know that.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The `NOT IN` keyword should be helpful :

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE username NOT IN (
    SELECT username
    FROM recentusers
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users
    LEFT JOIN recentusers USING (username) 
    WHERE recentusers.username IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a left join (which will perform faster than a subquery):

```
SELECT
    users.username
FROM
    users LEFT JOIN recentusers
        ON users.username = recentusers.username
WHERE
    recenterusers.username is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins should be faster than subqueries, though I do not really know if mysql supports this.

```
select * from users
left outer join recentusers
on users.key = recentusers.key
```

Comment: That's incorrect regarding MySQL, and your query doesn't list users that are **not** in the `recentusers` table: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: The query is right, concerning standard SQL syntax, look out for the outer keyword. Secondly I wrote that I do not know if MySql supports this syntax, since MySql cooks its own meal.

Comment: `@BeowulfOF`: the query is wrong, since you forgot to add `recentusers.key IS NULL`